# How to read the voltage of a bunch of batteries in parallel?

Tags: parallel, thevenin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8cesj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What are the equivalent/thevenin voltage?
It is very confusing, even with just one battery, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdBLbA.png)</sup>

Are the voltage 0? Since the resistor exhaust all the energy that the battery gives it.

Comment: if the voltage is the same on both sides of the resistor, is any energy lost? Remember to choose the same reference for 0V unless you mean across R.

Comment: If the batteries are perfectly then the voltage would only depend on the load. If not then it also depends on each battery.

Comment: Now consider only the V(R#) differences to determine the real cell voltage and the R's combine to a lower value for the whole.

Comment: Consider only the theoretical short circuit current of each cell and add, then the invert the resistances = conductance (S) and add. then invert sum back to R.  What if one cell was low?

Comment: The single cell always starts with the internal cell voltage 1V then drops with a load resistor when it approaches the internal R

Comment: Here's a bunch of cells and switches, ANYthing can be changed... http://tinyurl.com/yd3mgrwu

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one battery in series with one resistor, then the circuit is already in Thevenin equivalent form.  The output voltage with no load is simply the battery voltage since no current flows through the resistor as the circuit is not complete. With five circuits in parallel, the Thevenin resistance is just the parallel combination of the five resistors.  Since they are identical, the Thevenin resistance if 1/5 the value of one resistor. The Thevenin voltage can be found by just shorting out four of the batteries and calculating the output voltage and then multiplying the result by five since there are five identical circuits.  The result is equal to the voltage of one battery. The overall effect of putting five identical circuits in parallel is to reduce the Thevenin resistance by a factor of five but with the same Thevenin voltage. The only way the output voltage would be zero is if you short the output.  Then all of the battery voltage appears across the resistor.

Comment: How Thevenin voltage just be that of the battery with no current flowing through the resistor?

Comment: The way I find potential difference to imagine an electron flowing through the resistor and the battery. Is it even legitimate to assume no current would flow? What is the point of that?